# TypeScript. Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to develop a web app where input takes the text file of the book and processes it and the number of popular words But the following error is happening:

Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange.

Help me pls!!

```js
import * as _ from 'lodash';

function show(input) {
  const file = input.files[0];

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
  reader.onload = () => {
    const res = _.words(reader.result, /[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]{4,}/gim);
    const result = _.flow([
      _.countBy,
      _.toPairs,
      _.partial(_.orderBy, _, 1, 'desc'),
      _.partial(_.take, _, 10),
    ]);

    const txt = result(res).map(([word, num]) => `<tr><td>${word}<td>${num}`).join('');
    const out = document.getElementById('out');
    out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', txt);
  };
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>file</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="drop-area">
        Drag and drop file here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="file-read">
    <div class="file-input">
        <label class="custom-file-upload">
            <input type="file" id="input-file" onchange="show(this)" accept=".txt, .pdf, .epub, .fb2">
            Upload a file
        </label>
    </div>

    <a href="">Reset</a>

</div>

<div id="table-div">
    <table id="out"></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are they two different files. If yes,I don't see your js file imported in the script in html anywhere. If no please upload full code.

Comment: Not an ounce of typescript is present in this code

Answer (score 1):

How does the javascript connect to your HTML? I don't see any script tag or anything. If you load it somehow, show us how, so we can understand if the error is the linking. If it is linked somehow, maybe the onchange is called before the script was executed and therefore the show function was not defined yet.